# Is it possible to permutate shell globbing expressions?

Tags: shell, ordering, globbing

When using normal shell globbing, `*` often matches files in lexicographic order. For certain reason, sometimes I don't want this behavior. Is there a way to scramble matching results so their order is at random? I am specially interested in zsh solutions but this is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls | sort -R
```

might work for you.

Comment: `$( ls | sort -R )` would even be a drop-in replacement for `*` in most cases.